# Percentage of a quantity

Tags: probability, percentages

Concrete is sometimes made from 1 part cement, 4 parts blue metal and 3 parts sand. Find the percentage of cement used

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{(1+4+3)}*100$

Comment: I think we are missing some information here. What does "sometimes" mean?

Comment: In construction it's standardized. For personal use it isn't. Example - I made a shed foundation with my uncle which had less than the normal amount of cement.

Answer (score 2):

There is a total of 8 parts in any quantity of concrete: 1 part cement, 4 parts metal and 3 parts sand.
1 part out of 8 parts total is cement.
This gives us 1/8 = 0.125 = 12.5% cement.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage of cement used is $(\frac{1}{1+4+3}\times 100)\%$.